# Ie11-object doesn't support property or bind issue

Tags: javascript, angular, cross-browser

As part of my requirement i developed a functionality which opens a new tab upon a button click and while loading the new page in new tab there are 5 service calls. This is working fine in chrome browser but in IE browser it's throwing below error.
Also it's working as expected in Edge browser also.
1.first time on click of link i'm getting below error in IE, but 2 click it is working as expected.

> Blockquote
> These are the errors I'm getting.

1.Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'
2.Expected identifier.
3.Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
4.Expected identifier, string or number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Explain the problem, add relevant error messages, provide a [mcve] that shows the actual problem

Comment: Same link as above: _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_